# two row's are marked by one tap in UITableView selection list

Tags: uitableview, selection, checkmark, reuseidentifier

i'm trying to do a selection list in UITableView but whenever i tap in a row, two row are marked. For example if i tap the first row it adds a checkmark to row = 0 and row = 11. I think the problem is caused  by reuse of cells but i don't understand how solve it.

I attach my code .h:

```
@interface tabellaViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *listaingredienti;
@end
```

and my code .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_listaingredienti = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"formaggio", @"crudo", @"pomodorini", @"fossa", @"bresaola", @"funghi", @"salame", @"fontina", @"rucola", @"radicchio", @"peperoni", @"ciccioli", @"squacquerone", @"gorgonzola", @"salsiccia", @"cipolla", @"feta", @"acciughe", @"pecorino",  nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [_listaingredienti count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [_listaingredienti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
                            animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I've seen [UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath add additional checkmark at tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370311/uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-add-additional-checkmark-at-tap) where there is a similar post but i already use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
i'm just solved my question. Actually, the problem was in reuse of cells, but this code fix it.

Just replace in cellForRowAtIndexPath::

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

with:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyReuseIdentifier %d",indexPath.row];
```